# Remaining leading zero after adding in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

When employee_id is added by one, leading zeros are removed in the following query.

`` SELECT SUBSTRING(MAX(ID), 6, 4)+1 FROM `employee` ``

Here is my table.

```
ID        | Name
=================
Empl_0001 | Alex
Empl_0002 | John
```

How can I remain leading zeros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:

You can use `LPAD`. here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rbDhDgXFkaVBGDne9A578p/2). this will keep your ID length of 4.

```
SELECT 
    LPAD( SUBSTRING(MAX(ID), 6, 4) + 1 , 4, '0') as ID
FROM myTable
```

Option 2:
You can use `concat` and here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rbDhDgXFkaVBGDne9A578p/1).

```
SELECT 
  concat('000', SUBSTRING(MAX(ID), 6, 4)+1) 
FROM myTable
```

Output:

```
| ID   |
| ---- |
| 0003 |
```

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question. If the id is 1234, I get 0001234. In this case, I would like to keep length in 4. Do I have to use If statement?

Comment: @ewef  I have updated my answer with second option `LAPD` which will satisfy your need.